# how long can deleted emails stay in recoverable items folders in Archive mail box?

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I notice there is a retention tag can help you move emails from recoverable items folders in main mailbox to recoverable items folders in archive mailbox.

May i know default how long can it stay in recoverable items folders in Archive mail box? How to change it? Any maximum limit? Thanks! Sorry to ask this silly question, I just cannot find a Microsoft explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you've permanently deleted an item in Microsoft Outlook or Outlook on the web (formerly known as Outlook Web App), the item is moved to a folder ( **Recoverable Items > Deletions**) and kept there for ***14 days***, by default. You can change how long items are kept, up to a maximum of ***30 days***.

To change the retention periode to 30 days you simply use the Set-Mailbox command in PowerShell when logged onto the Exchange Online Tenant:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity user@domain.tld -RetainDeletedItemsFor 30
```

For more information on the topic check the [Microsofts docs page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/change-deleted-item-retention)

Comment: then how long can it stay in the recoverable items folders in Archive mailbox?

Comment: It is the same. After you delete the email from any deleted items folder and the email goes to the recovery bin, it will be there for 14 days standard.